# Como tratar igualmente strings acentuadas e sem acento num LIKE

Tags: mysql

Estou realizando uma query onde preciso buscar os dados baseado na primeira letra de uma string, por exemplo.

Acessórios;
`select * from tabela where column LIKE 'a%'`

Porém, se eu passar alguma letra que tenha acento cadastrada no bd eu não consigo restagar usando apenas a letra sem o acento, por exemplo `o%` e `Ó%`, curiosamente quando faço a exibição dos dados separados por ordem alfabetica as palavras com acento agudo `Ó` elas aparecem junto a letra `a`.

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa usar o collation correto em sua base de dados.

Por exemplo, se a coluna da sua tabela que vai ser pesquisada está em UTF-8, precisa usar a collation `utf8_unicode_ci` ("ci" no final das collations do MySQL é "case insensitive", ou seja, maiúsculas e minúsculas tem o mesmo peso).

Para saber as *collations* disponíveis, basta isto:

```
SHOW CHARACTER SET;
```

Exemplo de resultado:

```
+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------+
| Charset  | Description                 | Default collation   |
+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------+
| latin1   | cp1252 West European        | latin1_swedish_ci   |
| latin2   | ISO 8859-2 Central European | latin2_general_ci   |
| ascii    | US ASCII                    | ascii_general_ci    |
| cp1250   | Windows Central European    | cp1250_general_ci   |

... truncado para melhor leitura. deixei os mais comuns pra nós ...

| utf8     | UTF-8 Unicode               | utf8_general_ci     |
| ucs2     | UCS-2 Unicode               | ucs2_general_ci     |
| cp852    | DOS Central European        | cp852_general_ci    |
| utf8mb4  | UTF-8 Unicode               | utf8mb4_general_ci  |
| utf16    | UTF-16 Unicode              | utf16_general_ci    |
+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------+
```

Para fins de teste, a solução do colega Victor é boa, mas para uso definitivo, convém modificar a tabela ou a coluna para que não precise do `COLLATE` na *query*.

Usar `COLLATE` na *query* é apenas para soluções excepcionais e pontuais, quando o *default* não serve para situações de **exceção**.

O Manual descreve bem toda a parte das *collations*, mas está em inglês:

> `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset.html`

### Convertendo charset da tabela

Para alterar o collation de uma tabela:

```
ALTER TABLE <nome> COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; -- ponha o collation correto
```

Para **converter** o charset de uma tabela:

**MUITA ATENÇÃO!**  NUNCA use o comando abaixo se a tabela não estiver se comportando corretamente. Uma vez que esteja tudo certo, aí você pode precisar converter os dados, e só aí pode usar essa opção, pois ela mexe nos dados da tabela. FAÇA SEMPRE BACKUP. Pronto, agora você pode por o mouse em cima do amarelinho pra ver o comando :)

> ALTER TABLE  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: Como faço para trocar o `character set` da coluna? tentei implementar o collate na query e recebi o seguinte erro.
`ERROR: COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'`

Comment: Exato, não é esse collation. Veja na tabela que pra latin1 o collation é outro! `latin1_swedish_ci` é pra te atender bem. Vou complementar a resposta.

Comment: consegui resolver o problema, porém agora no HTML a letra `Ó` esta aparecendo "�"  mesmo salvando o arquivo com `utf-8` e declarando o meta do html como `utf-8` tambem.

Comment: Sim, pq sua tabela não está em utf, sua tabela está em latin1 e sua página em utf. Pus a solução da conversão na pergunta, mas FAÇA BACKUP ANTES, pois vc pode zoar a tabela toda.

Comment: a tabela esta como `utf8_general_ci` tambem.

Comment: O mais interessante é que as letras `Ç` e `Á` são exibidas normalmente, só a letra `Ó` que não.

Comment: Isso pode ser algum erro no charset (não confundir com collation - collation é a parte usada nas buscas e ordenações - charset é o jeito que os caracteres são armazenados)

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coluna LIKE 'a%' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```