# PHP Sistema de pesquisa ignorar letras maiusculas e somar palavras chaves

Tags: php, query

Tenho um simples sistema de pesquisa que busca valores no BD e exibe na página.
Na tabela tenho uma coluna chamada palavraschaves onde são cadastradas as palavras que deixo como parâmetro de pesquisa.
Preciso de duas coisas. A primeira é que ao digitar a palavra com letra maiúscula ou minúscula ele entenda da mesma maneira sem que eu precisa cadastrar ambas no BD. A segunda coisa é que ele some as palavras na busca. Por exemplo: cadastrei as palavras na tabela na seguinte ordem; casa construcao telhado. Se eu digito telhado casa não me retorna nada, apenas se pesquisar por um dos dois. Quero que ele busque pelas duas.

**Código**

```
$busca = trim($_POST['busca']);
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pesquisa_clientes WHERE palavraschaves LIKE '%".$busca."%' ORDER BY nome");
$numRegistros = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if ($numRegistros != 0) {


echo "<h4 class='result'>Resultados para: <b> " . $busca . "</b></h4><br />";

        while ($usuario = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)) {

echo "<div id='resultados'>";
echo "<img src='images/clientes/".$usuario->logo."' alt='Foto de exibição' /><br />";
echo utf8_encode("<h4><b> " . $usuario->nome . "</b></h4><br />");
echo utf8_encode("<p><span><b> " . $usuario->subcategoria . "</b></span></p><br /><br />");
echo utf8_encode("<p><b>Bairro:</b> " . $usuario->bairro . "</p><br />");
echo "<p><b>Telefone:</b> " . $usuario->telefone . "</p><br />";
echo "<a href='". $usuario->link_cliente. "'><b>Saiba Mais</b></a><br /><br />";
echo "</div>";
}
} else {
        echo "<h4 class='result'>Nada foi encontrado com a palavra:<b> ".$busca."</b></h4>";
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Recomendo que limite a pergunta a um problema específico.

Comment: Poderia mostrar como as palavras estão inseridas no banco ?
Não sei se elas estão inseridas separadamente, ou da forma que o usuário digita na pesquisa. Mostre-me isso.

Comment: Separei por espaço simples: casa carro mesa de plastico

Comment: O primeiro caso tem vários e vários assuntos aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/144251/como-tratar-igualmente-strings-acentuadas-e-sem-acento-num-like/144265#144265, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192156/sql-like-%C3%A9-case-sensitivecaso-sensitivo/192373#192373, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72139/qual-codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-caracteres-collation-devo-usar-em-mysql/72142#72142.....

Comment: Turkish, escolha um encode do banco/tabela que termine em _ci (que quer dizer "case insensitive"), isto resolverá o problema das letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas. Para o problema da busca, recomendo uso de match against do mysql. Já dei uma resposta uma vez explicando o uso do match against, veja essa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187858/fazer-uma-busca-independente-da-ordem-das-palavras-chave/187895#187895

Comment: Amigos. Não tentei o código que me passaram porque a do Leo solucionou meu problema anterior. Mas alterei a pergunta pois surgiu uma nova.

Comment: Reverti a última edição pois muda o sentido, invalidando as respostas existentes até o momento.

Comment: Se vc quer matar dois coelhos numa tacada só, coloque o banco como utf8_general_ci. Assim não precisará fazer tanto esforço para ambos os casos, a acentuação e caixa alta ou baixa.. Saliento que não é "a solução", mas uma opção.

Comment: Resposta editada para atender acentuação

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **A respeito de maiúsculas e minusculas** não está muito clara sua pergunta.
  Vou supor que as palavras no banco estão todas em minusculas e o usuário digitar maiúscula ou minuscula. Nesse caso basta usar a função  [**strtolower**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtolower.php) que converte todos os caracteres para minúsculas
- **Sobre "somar palavras chaves"** utilize REGEXP, explode e implode.

[**DEMO**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/select-com-regex.php)

```
$busca = trim($_POST['busca']);
//para remover os espaços duplicados.
$busca = preg_replace('/\s(?=\s)/', '', $busca);
//tudo em minusculas
$busca = strtolower($busca)

//quando uma pessoa digitar umas palavras, elas são explodidas pelo espaço
$exp = explode(" ", $busca); // separando pelo espaço

//e em seguida são implodidas pela | (barra vertical)
$imp = implode("|", $exp); // unindo os valores pela |

//a consulta é como segue
SELECT * FROM pesquisa_clientes WHERE palavraschaves REGEXP '$imp' ORDER BY nome
```

> A | (barra vertical) é necessária para o uso do REGEXP, ela simboliza o OR "ou", ou seja, vai buscar entre os valores separados pela | (barra vertical).

**Para converter acentuações pode usar a função**

```
Function TirarAcento( $texto ) 
{
    $array1 = array(   "á", "à", "â", "ã", "ä", "é", "è", "ê", "ë", "í", "ì", "î", "ï", "ó", "ò", "ô", "õ", "ö", "ú", "ù", "û", "ü", "ç"); 

    $array2 = array(   "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "e", "e", "e", "e", "i", "i", "i", "i", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "u", "u", "u", "u", "c"); 

    return str_replace( $array1, $array2, $texto ); 
}  

 $busca = trim($_POST['busca']);
 $busca = preg_replace('/\s(?=\s)/', '', $busca);

 $busca = strtolower($busca);

 $busca = TirarAcento($busca);
 ............................
 ............................
 ............................
```

> chame a função   `TirarAcento` apos a função   `strtolower`

Quer saber porque? passe o mouse na área abaixo amarelada

> porque a função `TirarAcento` está fazendo a troca de letras acentuados somente para minusculas, portanto é indispensável colocar os termos de busca primeiramente em minusculas com a função  `strtolower`

Comment: Leo. Seu exemplo me salvou. Exatamente o que eu procurava. Eu alterei a minha pergunta e o código conforme me passou e agora tenho apenas mais uma dúvida. Como converto as acentuações? Por exemplo: Eu cadastrei no BD as palavras sem acento, mas quero que quando pesquisa com acento ele faça a conversão. Assim seria o correto ou eu deveria cadastrar com acento e converter na hora da pesquisa?

Comment: Inclui a linha e me exibe o erro: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/html/oabobreiro.com.br/web/resultado.php on line 365. Alinha 365 está assim: $numRegistros = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

Comment: vou colocar uma função para os caracteres acentuados

Comment: Leo. Maravilha. Seu código é simples de entender, além de ser um código limpo é extremamente funcional. Estou me aperfeiçoando em PHP e mysqli e hoje você me foi um grande professor. Onde te dou uma estrela?

Answer (score 0):

Sobre as letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, acredito que a melhor forma é você definir como vai gravar as palavras no banco, se for maiúscula por exemplo, ao ler as palavras que o usuário digitou tu transforma aquela string em maiúscula com o strtoupper(string).
A segunda parte do problema, tu pode quebrar a string que o usuário digitou com o explode, feito isso, você vai ter um array com as palavras capturadas, ai basta usar o implode e separar os valores dos arrays por virgulas no seu select.

ficaria algo assim:

```
$busca = trim($_POST['busca']);
//transformo tudo em maiúsculo
$busca = strtoupper($busca)
//quebro a string nos espaços, e gravo no array
$array= explode(" ", $busca)
//where IN (valor1, valor2,valor3), uso o implode para coloca a virgula após cada valor do array
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pesquisa_clientes WHERE palavraschaves in ('.implode(',', array_map('intval', $array)).') ORDER BY nome");
```

não sei se esta funcionando por que não testei, mas a ideia é essa